# Bluetooth speakers very quiet over A2DP on 19.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

I have a pair of speakers connected to MR230 bluetooth receiver dongle. In Windows there is no problem with the setup, in Ubuntu 19.10 the sound is too quiet. I'd say, with everything maxed out to 150% and speaker volume at max, it sounds like 20-25% of Windows' max. The speakers are connected over A2TP sink, I have everything updated, here are relevant configs:

```
> pacmd list-cards
...
* index: 7
name: <bluez_sink.E8_07_BF_08_2B_F5.a2dp_sink>
driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME 
state: RUNNING
suspend cause: (none)
priority: 9950
volume: front-left: 62257 /  95% / -1.34 dB,   front-right: 62257 /  95% / -1.34 dB
balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 66.56 ms
max request: 4 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 11
sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
Stereo
used by: 1
linked by: 1
fixed latency: 46.33 ms
card: 3 <bluez_card.E8_07_BF_08_2B_F5>
module: 26
properties:
bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
device.description = "MR230"
device.string = "E8:07:BF:08:2B:F5"
device.api = "bluez"
device.class = "sound"
device.bus = "bluetooth"
device.form_factor = "headphone"
bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_07_BF_08_2B_F5"
bluez.class = "0x240418"
bluez.alias = "MR230"
device.icon_name = "audio-headphones-bluetooth"
ports:
headphone-output: Headphone (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
properties:
active port: <headphone-output>
```

When I use `pacmd set-sink-volume bluez_sink.E8_07_BF_08_2B_F5.a2dp_sink XXX` it changes the volume, but still around 90000 it's like 150% in `pavucontrol`, the sound is a bit distorted as well.

I've tried pre-boosting sound in `mpv`, but it results in horrible clipping.  Over HFS the sound is loud enough, but sounds horrible.

Bluetooth is provided by Intel AX200 module with the latest iwlwifi drivers and firmware from Intel's site.

Any idea what could be wrong?